# Why am I getting an empty output object in Panel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, panel, pipeline, pyviz

I have a parameterized input data class that outputs a loaded model into the next stage of pipeline:

```
class InputData(param.Parameterized):
    # placeholders for the incoming parameters
    load_sim_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=LoadAdhSimulation)
    att_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=Attributes)
    proj_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=projections.Projection)

    label = param.String(default='Basic Input', precedence=-1)

    def __init__(self, **params):
        super(InputData, self).__init__(**params)
        self.dat_files = []

        self.model = None

    # output the adh_viz object
    @param.output()
    def adh_viz(self):
        return self.load_data()

    @param.depends('load_sim_widget.load_netcdf', 'load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename',
                   'load_sim_widget.adh_directory', watch=True)
    def available_attributes(self):
        att_list = []

        # if netcdf is selected
        if self.load_sim_widget.load_netcdf:
            filename = os.path.join(self.load_sim_widget.adh_directory,
                                    self.load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename + '.nc')

            try:
                # open the xarray dataset (does not load into memory)
                ncdf = xr.open_dataset(filename)

            except FileNotFoundError:
                print('File Not Found: {}'.format(filename))
            else:
                with ncdf:
                    # enable and add all variables in the netcdf file
                    for var in ncdf.data_vars:
                        att_name = var.lower().replace(" ", "_")

                        # if the variable has results dimensions
                        if 'times' in ncdf[var].dims and 'nodes_ids' in ncdf[var].dims:
                            # add to the list
                            att_list.append(att_name)
                # close the dataset
                ncdf.close()

        # otherwise read from available *.dat files
        else:
            # read in extension dicts & standardize extensions
            ext_to_widget, widget_to_ext = attribute_dict()

            # fix
            ext_to_widget['error'] = ext_to_widget.pop('err_hyd')

            # get the list of filenames  # todo this isn't foolproof e.g. `SanDieg` finds files
            glob_items = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.load_sim_widget.adh_directory,
                                                self.load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename + '*.dat'))

            # convert filenames list to attribute list
            att_list = []
            for filename in glob_items:
                #     suffix.append(get_variable_from_file_name(filename))
                att_list.append(ext_to_widget[get_variable_from_file_name(filename)])

        # dictionary for naming inconsistencies # todo add complexity for err_con in future
        label_to_widget = {'error': 'error_hydro',
                           'depth-averaged_velocity': 'velocity'}

        # loop over the inconsistencies
        for key in label_to_widget.keys():
            # if this is found in the list
            if key in att_list:
                # remove the key
                att_list.remove(key)
                # add back in the corrected value
                att_list.append(label_to_widget[key])

        # adjust available attribute widgets based on available data
        for key, value in self.att_widget.params().items():
            # if this attribute wasn't in the list
            if key in att_list:
                # ensure the widget is enabled
                self.att_widget.params()[key].constant = False
                # set the widget value
                setattr(self.att_widget, key, True)
            elif key != 'name':
                # ensure the widget is enabled
                self.att_widget.params()[key].constant = False
                # uncheck the attribute
                setattr(self.att_widget, key, False)
                # disable attribute
                self.att_widget.params()[key].constant = True

    def load_data(self):
        # if file is netcdf
        if self.load_sim_widget.load_netcdf:

            self.model, avail_attributes = load_model(self.load_sim_widget.adh_directory,
                                                      project_name=self.load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename,
                                                      netcdf=self.load_sim_widget.load_netcdf)

        # request to load data from *dat files:
        else:
            # get a list of requested suffix strings
            slist = self.att_widget.suffix_list(value=True)

            # construct list of filenames
            fnames = []
            [fnames.append(os.path.join(self.load_sim_widget.adh_directory,
                                        self.load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename + '_' + x + '.dat')) for x in slist]
            # read the requested files
            self.model, avail_attributes = load_model(self.load_sim_widget.adh_directory,
                                           project_name=self.load_sim_widget.adh_root_filename,
                                           netcdf=False, crs=self.proj_widget.get_crs(), filenames=fnames)

        adh_viz = AdhViz()
        adh_viz.set_model(self.model)
        roams_model = None

        return adh_viz

    # visualize the page
    def panel(self):
        self.available_attributes()  # for the initial load
        return pn.Row(pn.Spacer(height=700), pn.Param(self.load_sim_widget, show_name=False),
                      pn.Param(self.att_widget, show_name=False), pn.Param(self.proj_widget, show_name=False),
                      name=self.label)
```

Then the next stage of the pipeline should injest the output from the first and visualize it.

```
class ViewResults(param.Parameterized):
    load_sim_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=LoadAdhSimulation)
    att_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=Attributes)
    proj_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=projections.Projection)

    display_range = param.ClassSelector(class_=display_opts.DisplayRangeOpts)
    cmap_opts = param.ClassSelector(class_=display_opts.ColormapOpts)

    adh_viz = param.ClassSelector(class_=AdhViz)

    wmts_widget = param.ClassSelector(class_=display_opts.WMTS)
    wireframe = param.ClassSelector(class_=display_opts.ShowElements)

    def __init__(self, **params):
        for k, p in self.params().items():
            if k in params or k == 'name':
                continue
            params[k] = p.class_()
        super(ViewResults, self).__init__(**params)

        self.annotator = ESAnnotator(path_type=gv.Path,
                                     crs=ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR,
                                     point_columns=['depth_elevation'],
                                     poly_columns=['name']
                                     )
        self.map_pane_ = pn.Spacer(width=0)
        self.analysis_pane_ = pn.Spacer(width=0)
        self.tool_pane_ = pn.Spacer(width=0)
        # self.adh_viz = adh_viz

    @property
    def tabs(self):
        result = pn.panel(self.adh_viz, parameters=['result_label'], show_name=False)

        disp_tab = pn.Column(self.wmts_widget, 
                             pn.Pane(self.cmap_opts, show_name=False),
                             pn.Pane(self.display_range, show_name=False),
                             pn.Pane(self.wireframe),
                             result)

        return [('Display', disp_tab)]

    # what to pass out of this page (for pipeline)
    @param.output()
    def output(self):
        pass

    # how to build this page
    def panel(self):
        return pn.panel(self.run)

    @param.depends('adh_viz.result_label', 'wireframe.mesh_elements') # never need watch=True
    def run(self):

        # create the meshes for the dynamic map
        meshes = self.adh_viz.create_animation2()

        if self.wireframe.mesh_elements is True:
            edgepaths_overlay = self.adh_viz.view_elements()  # transparent/ invisible overlay
        else:
            edgepaths_overlay = hv.Points(data=[])  # existing edgepaths overlay

        # Define function which applies colormap and color_range
        def apply_opts(obj, colormap, color_range):
            return obj.options(cmap=colormap, height=600, width=600).redim.range(**{obj.vdims[0].name: color_range}).options(
                clipping_colors={'NaN': 'transparent', 'min': 'transparent'})

        if meshes.label == 'scalar':

            # Apply the colormap and color range dynamically
            dynamic = hv.util.Dynamic(rasterize(meshes), operation=apply_opts,
                                      streams=[Params(self.cmap_opts), Params(self.display_range)]
                                      ) * \
                      self.wmts_widget.view() * \
                      self.annotator.polys * \
                      self.annotator.points * \
                      edgepaths_overlay
        elif meshes.label == 'vector':
            # Apply the colormap and color range dynamically
            dynamic = hv.util.Dynamic(rasterize(vectorfield_to_paths(meshes, color='Magnitude', magnitude='Magnitude',
                                      scale=0.05), aggregator='mean', cmap=process_cmap('viridis'), precompute=True),
                                      operation=apply_opts, streams=[Params(self.cmap_opts),
                                      Params(self.display_range)]) * \
                      self.wmts_widget.view() * \
                      self.annotator.polys * \
                      self.annotator.points * \
                      edgepaths_overlay

        time = pn.panel(self.adh_viz, parameters=['time'], widgets={'time': pn.widgets.DiscretePlayer}, show_name=False)
        # time = pn.panel(self.adh_viz, parameters=['time'], show_name=False)

        hv_panel = pn.panel(dynamic)

        map_pane = pn.Column(hv_panel[0], pn.Row(pn.Spacer(width=100), time))

        tool_pane = pn.Tabs(*self.tabs)

        return pn.Row(map_pane, pn.Spacer(width=100, height=900), pn.Column(tool_pane, pn.Pane(LOGO, width=300)))
```

Here is the dashboard:

```
def results_dashboard(directory=os.path.join(ROOTDIR, 'data/SanDiego'), rootname='SanDiego'):
    # generic single simulation options
    load_sim_widget = LoadAdhSimulation(adh_root_filename=rootname, adh_directory=directory)
    att_widget = Attributes()

    # projection options
    proj_widget = projections.Projection(name='')

    # generic display options
    wmts_widget = display_opts.WMTS(name='')
    display_range = display_opts.DisplayRangeOpts()
    cmap_opts = display_opts.ColormapOpts()
    wireframe = display_opts.ShowElements(name='')

    # create stages for pipeline
    stages = [
        ('Input', InputData(load_sim_widget=load_sim_widget, att_widget=att_widget, proj_widget=proj_widget)),
        ('View', ViewResults(load_sim_widget=load_sim_widget, att_widget=att_widget, proj_widget=proj_widget,
                             display_range=display_range, cmap_opts=cmap_opts, wmts_widget=wmts_widget,
                             wireframe=wireframe))
    ]

    # create the pipeline
    pipeline = pn.pipeline.Pipeline(stages, debug=True)

    # modify button width (not exposed)
    pipeline.layout[0][1]._widget_box.width = 100
    pipeline.layout[0][2]._widget_box.width = 100

    # return a display of the pipline
    return pipeline.layout
```

However, when I run this dashboard, the second stage is just displaying an empty adh_viz object. I have made sure that the data is loaded, but it just seems like its not passing it properly.

I had this code working properly a few days ago, but I made a minor change to load the data EARLIER in the process (should be unrelated to pipeline) and now it doesn't work.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

EDITED TO ADD:
When I extract the `results_dashboard` code out of the class and just run it in a jupyter notebook. I get an error in the console:

`Error: Model 'ClearTool' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage.`

BUT, if I use the same kernel (don't restart) but rerun the imports, my pipeline will successfully pass data from one stage to the next.

Unfortunately this doesn't work if I leave the `results_dashboard` code inside of the class.

EDITED AGAIN:
It WILL work with `results_dashboard` class if I add panel, hv, and hv.extension('bokeh') to the imports on the notebook and reload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a race condition with my imports. I moved `hv.extension('bokeh')` to be the last import and that fixed it.